# generate longest possible palindrome for a given string

Tags: java, palindrome

I've been trying to generate the longest possible [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) *included* in a given string, in java. 
But, it always ended up in errors.

Let me provide the sample input and output so that it may help .

Input: `This is a sample string for testing`

Output: `ttissaepeassitt`

It would be great if anyone could solve me this!!

Thank You!!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Comment: Sorry, but asking people here to write programs for you is not going to work.  Besides, you won't learn to program by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive algorithm:

```
public String findPalindrom(String input){
   String palindrom = "";
   for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
      char c = input.charAt(i); // Explore the string from the beginning, char by char
      for(int j=input.length()-1; j>i; j--){ // Explore the string from the end, char by char
         if(input.charAt(j)==c){ // We found a letter for the palindrom
            String newPalindrom = c + findPalindrom(input.substring(i+1, j)) + c;
            if(newPalindrom.length() > palindrom.length())
               palindrom = newPalindrom;
         }
      }
   }
   if(palindrom.length()==0 && input.length()>0)
      palindrom += input.charAt(0); // manage the case where the only palindrom possible is a single char.
   return palindrom;
}
```